# Keeping a lower value in some cases and a higher value in some other

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

Geography student here. We recently started to use Raster Calculator and I have a problem in this one case.

So we have three types of roads with a buffer zone. The road itself has value 0, a 1000-2000 unit buffer around it has value of 10 and the rest has value of 5. How can I add these 3 maps by keeping the lowest value except of the cases where value of 5 meets 10?

Comment: Generally speaking, this case demonstrates why it's important to encode arbitrary values in a way that helps, not hurts, you. But a logical expression can certainly be constructed to meet this criteria. What have you tried?

Comment: "The rest" has a value of 5: which "rest"? 0 to 1000 m or everythin > 2000 m? How wide is the road? What exactly do you want to achieve: to get all the roads/ 0-values? What is the problem you encounter using raster calculator? Sorry, to me the question is not clear. Please edit the question an add more details. A screenshot might also help.